# customized CKEDITOR_BASEPATH setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to have a customized CKEDITOR_BASEPATH as referred https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.

My app runs on a baseURL as followed
http://localhost:3000/tutorsaround

Therefore I change my "app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/basepath.js.erb" as

```
<%
  base_path = '/tutorsaround'
  if ENV['PROJECT'] =~ /editor/i
    base_path << "/#{Rails.root.basename.to_s}/"
  end
  base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
  base_path << '/ckeditor/'
  puts "#{base_path}"
%>
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '<%= base_path %>';
```

However, when i go to different page, I saw an error in console.
GET http://localhost:3000/tutorsaround/boards/tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=F0RD 404 (Not Found)

It seems like the path has inserted after each sub path rather than http://localhost:3000/

So my question is how can I add a base_path for CKeditor that the base url would always be http://localhost:3000/tutorsaround and whenever it want to refer the js source, it would be http://localhost:3000/tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/......

EDIT2
I puts the base_path in terminal it outputs "tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/"
My problem is that this string is not concatenated after the "localhost:3000/". However, any page that using the CKEditor, will concatenate this string on the page url. For example, if the "localhost:3000/boards" has the CK editor, then it will try to get the resource through "http://localhost:3000/boards/tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=F0RD"
If the "localhost:3000/boards/1" has used the CKEditor, then it will try to get from "http://localhost:3000/boards/1/tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=F0RD"

Comment: I make the demo site into production, well you can use this test account to see the failure. http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8010/tutorsaround
(email: 1@ta.com password:11111111)
After login, you can go the below link to see the failure of load in comment.
http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8010/tutorsaround/boards/new

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *Please check the code samples below again due to initially I posted them without your custom path prefix*

Try with removing the condition (leave the line inside of it):

```
<%
  base_path = '/tutorsaround'
  base_path << "/#{Rails.root.basename.to_s}/"
  base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
  base_path << '/ckeditor/'
 %>
```

or if that doesn't work try with:

```
<%
  base_path = '/tutorsaround'
  base_path << Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
  base_path << '/ckeditor/'
%>
```

**Edit2**

In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` add basepath dependency before init:

```
//= require ckeditor/basepath
//= require ckeditor/init
```

Comment: I actually tried both already. The only thing is my index page is not in localhost, instead it is in localhost/tutorsaround so I need a base_path. However, once I have the base_path, the behavior is strange cause anytime I went to a subpage, for example 'localhost/tutorsaround/board/', the corresponding path for the ckeditor becomes 'localhost/tutorsaround/board/tutorsaround/ckeditor....'

Comment: I made the website in production so you may see the error.  I have an update in my original post

Comment: In your sample code, you are missing '/' before tutorsaround - in the first line where you define your basepath.

Comment: I changed. However, that seems not the key problem

Comment: Can you share your application layout page or wherever you include ckeditor as an asset?

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't get your question. I was basically following the document on https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor  I think ckeditor has become a model in my 'models' directory

Comment: If you check https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#usage (the require part) you'll see that it has `//= require ckeditor/init`. That line includes this file: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/init.js.erb Try to debug that code (put logs) and see why your basepath is not correctly formed. 
You can also put logs in the code mentioned before to see if it gets executed at all.
Long story short: put `//= require ckeditor/basepath` before `//= require ckeditor/init`

Comment: The code is been executed as I have add one line to put the base_path in terminal. The problem is not basepath not correctly formed but how to concatenate with the whole url is not correct. I have an update in my post.

Comment: From your edit: "I puts the base_path in terminal it outputs "tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/" -> that is your problem, the output should be "/tutorsaround/assets/ckeditor/" with the leading slash.

Comment: I check the terminal on Chrome Firefox and the whole url is correct. The problem is in production when a server run with several web applications. If in server, there is just this one and my index url is just 'http://example.com', that will be no problem when the second line of my code change to "base_path = ''" However, when my server runs several web apps and each apps have an unique base address for example, in my case "http://example.com/tutorsaround" and I use the code stated above, the js path is wrong. The problem it's not correct not for of the leading slash, as I checked